# Destructuring JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, api, object, object-destructuring

How do I destructure the object below?

I want to get some data from the property `caps_`. I'm getting this data from an API and every time I try it returns `undefined`.

```
tabs_: {
    Promise {
      Session {
        id_: '4083ce6f-f536-41bd-9f4e-9c1a66c4486f',
        caps_: Capabilities { map_: [Map]; }
    }
  }
}
```

Here`s my code...

```
const caps = tabs_.caps_;
console.log(caps);
```

Even when I try to get the value of `id_` , it returns `undefined` yet I can see a value in there without writing any code.

Comment: is `tabs_` a promise? Perhaps you forgot to `await` your response from API?

Comment: sadly, it still doesn`t work.

Comment: You will need to show the code how `tabs_` gets set...